# Git credential gpg/pass TTY-only setup fails with "fatal: GPG_TTY is not set" eventhough it is

Tags: git, gnupg, tty, git-credential-manager, gpg-agent

I try to make Git-credential-manager-core to work on ubuntu with fish in wsl2 following instructions from https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/linuxcredstores.md. I went with option 2.GPG/Pass and as I understand on wsl2 I fall into "Headless/TTY-only sessions" category.

I have generated gpg keys and have initialized pass utility. I don't understand whether I need to have gpg-agent deamon running as the instruction only states "you must configured gpg-agent with a pin-entry program". I do run it with
`gpg-agent --daemon`

Finaly, I have the **GPG_TTY** variable set as indicated by
`echo $GPG_TTY`
returning
*/dev/pts/0*.

Running `git push origin master` results in error message:

```
fatal: GPG_TTY is not set; add `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` to your profile.
```

#### So why does it lie to me?

And in general any help concerning setup of git credentials is very welcome as I am lost with what tool is responsible for what and whether I need to manualy run gpg-agent.
*Thanks in advance!*

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 running in windows subsystem for linux 2 with fish shell. I only want to be able to push to my private repositories without looking up github token everytime.

Comment: It's almost guaranteed that the problem has something to do with WSL. It's probably somehow eating the environment variable.

Comment: How did you set `GPG_TTY`? May be it's simply not exported?

Comment: Yes, it is simply not exported! Previously I didn't know what exporting does. Thanks!

Comment: And indeed now git gcmc works wonderfully.